# What is the video saying at 6:10, was it "write off" or "ride off"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

The [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXO9VK1uyFs&t=5m32s) starts automatically at 5 mintues 32 seconds (for a bit of context)

The word is mentiond around 6:08.

He says: "...plus you've got a sheet of metal down there to protect it on the side to some extent because the underside is pretty well exposed and if you've got a shot in there you'd (**write the tank off/ride the tank off**) pretty quickly."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Write off**

An item is "written off" (accepted as a loss) if it has been too badly damaged to practically repair.

> chiefly British : something (such as a damaged vehicle) or someone regarded or conceded as a loss

- [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/write%20off)

Comment: For clarity, "written off" is an accounting term, describing when an accounting journal entry would be made to move the property from the asset category to the expense category, and hence remove it from the company's balance sheet (lists of assets and liabilities). Thus, the use of writing—to "write" it off (or out of) the accounting ledger. We use this colloquially to mean counting something once considered valuable to be worthless, whether that is an object, an endeavor, or a relationship.

Comment: This is not a "chiefly British" term.

Comment: @tchrist take it up with Merriam Webster